# ¿Hay alguna forma de eliminar el botón "atras" de los formularios de google?

Tags: formularios

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de eliminar el botón "atrás" de los formularios de google. He visto que hay una forma de eliminarlo de la vista previa si en inspeccionar elimino [image: este trozo de código]

pero claro yo quisiera eliminarlo del formulario. He visto también que desde el formulario puedo añadir complementos. En editor se secuencias de comandos me aparece esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero no sé que tendría que escribir ahí para que desaparezca el botón de atrás. 
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

```
function artex_init()
{
  this.iface.__init();

/* Desabilitamos los botones estándar para evitar trabajar con el dataset */
  this.child("pushButtonAcceptContinue").close();
  this.child("pushButtonFirst").close();
  this.child("pushButtonLast").close();
  this.child("pushButtonNext").close();
  this.child("pushButtonPrevious").close();
}
```